# Find WebElement base of text condition

Tags: selenium

I have an autocomplete `list` that opens once I type some text into a text field and each element in the list looks like this:

```
<div class="tt-dataset">
   <span class="tt-suggestions" style="display: block;">
      <div class="tt-suggestion">
         <div style="white-space: normal;">
            <p>
               <span class="ok-circle"></span>
               <strong>name</strong>
               <a class="edit" href="bla bla">Edit</a>
            </p>
            <p>address</p>
            <p>phone</p>
            <p></p>
         </div>
      </div>
```

I get the list this way:

```
val list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.tt-dataset div.tt-suggestion"))
```

In some cases `address` and `phone` are empty. When this happens, I want to filter them out in my selector so that the `list` contains only elements where `address` and `phone` are not empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually didn't get what do you want?? do you want to get all text??? or any thing else??? please clear your question

Comment: and it's `driver.findElements`...may be typo mistake..

Comment: Currently my selector is return list, now i want to return list but in each element i want that the first p element (where i have address in my exapmle) and the second p element (where i have phone in my exapmle) will not be empty but some string

Comment: means do you want the list of `p` elements??

Comment: this code is not in Java

Comment: the typo is only because i dont have my ide...

Comment: `val list`, `By.cssselector` and lack of semi-colon will all give you a compilation error in Java. Hence it must be something else. Not sure how IDE is related to java either - they are entirely different things.