# Multiple XPATH condition

Tags: selenium, xpath

Please see this `element`:

```
<div class="tt-dataset">
   <span class="tt-suggestions" style="display: block;">
      <div class="tt-suggestion">
         <div style="white-space: normal;">
            <p>
               <span class="ok-circle"></span>
               <strong>name</strong>
               <a class="edit" href="bla bla">Edit</a>
            </p>
            <p>address</p>
            <p>phone</p>
            <p></p>
         </div>
      </div>
```

So i want to take this element with condition that this `p` element test is not empty:

```
<p>address</p>
<p>phone</p>
```

This is what i have try:

```
(//div[@class='tt-dataset']//div[@class='tt-suggestion']//p[normalize-space(text())!=''])[1]
```

Currently this selector i check only the first `p element`, how can i do `And` and return the  `<div class="tt-dataset">` if this 2 p elements test is not empty ?

Comment: just remove `[1]` ?

Comment: This is the same question as your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455632/find-webelement-base-of-text-condition. Please don't post more than one question asking the same thing. Pick one and delete the other. If you have additional info to add, edit the question and add the details.